# Tridion 2013 MessageCenter, how to display message?

Tags: cme, 2013, gui-extensions

I would like to show a message in the new (and improved) Tridion 2013 MessageCenter.

In Tridion 2011 I used the following code:
 `$messages.registerNotification(data);`

However, this does not work in Tridion 2013.

Any ideas?

Comment: just tried on the chrome console $messages.registerNotification("hi there") and it worked as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this.

```
var msg = $messages.createMessage(Tridion.MessageCenter.Implementation.Notification, "Text", "Title", false/true, false/true);
$messages.registerMessage(msg);
```

Answer (score 6):

I haven't seen any changes with regards to the `$messages` API between 2011 and 2013, the following calls all work fine on 2011 and 2013 for me:

```js
$messages.registerNotification("custom notification message");
$messages.registerError("custom error message", null, null, null, true);
$messages.registerWarning("custom warning message", null, null, true);
```

Even using the predefined messages from the resource bundle still work for me:

```js
$messages.registerNotification($localization.getEditorResource("PublishPopupSentToPublishQueue", "tcm:0-0-0");
```

So I'm expecting something else is wrong, maybe your `data` object is not defined?

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to explore the SignalR and Message Center integration.

A step by step process has been explained very nicely by Robert and Will on SDL Tridion World site.

You may refer the link below for details:

http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/signalr_messagecenter.aspx

Comment: You're preaching to the choir Pankaj - Robert was a co-author of that article :)

Comment: Yeah, Robert is a co-author with Will Price of this fantastic article

Comment: robrtc from this post = Robert from the fantastic article :-)